# Способы устранения ошибки, возникающей при отсутствии элемента

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть кнопка на странице. Но есть он не всегда, а при определённых условиях, заданных на бэкенде.
И, соответственно, когда элемента нет, то возникает ошибка: *Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null*.

Постепенно я пришёл к двум способам решения проблемы.

1. **Классический** (недостатки: дополнительная переменная, дополнительная вложенность)

```
const button = document.querySelector('#showmore');
if (button)
{
  button.onclick = function() { 
      ...
  }
}
```

2. **Экзотический** (недостатки: создание лишнего пустого объекта)

```
(document.querySelector('#showmore') || {}).onclick = function() {
  ...
}
```

Мне очень нравится второй способ, т.к. он очень "ненагруженный", и я его воспринимаю, как красивый хак. Но некоторые говорят, что это "плохое решение". Пожалуйста, помогите определиться.

Comment: Напиши в поддержку разработчиков JS, пусть к вечеру добавят [безопасный вызов](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls), чтоб было так `document.querySelector('#showmore')?.onclick = function(){}`

Comment: Некоторые это я :) . Второй способ вводит других в заблуждение. Приходится гадать зачем вы создаёте объект, который сразу исчезнет. Во вложенности из первого варианта нет никаких проблем, притом её можно избежать легко, вот так: `if (button) button.onclick = .........`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg поддержка меньше 90%
https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я, к сожалению или счастью, всегда использую в коде скобки.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg и ещё такой код не будет работать `)?.onclick = function`, потому что присвоение так не работает. Только последовательность через точку или квадратные скобки.

Comment: @МихаилТестов ну скобки это нормально, но желание сделать экзотично потому что воспринимаете как красоту - это не хорошо. Пока что я тут один выступаю за это, но поверьте, такое не приветствуется.

Answer (score 0):

Если версия Chrome ^80

```js
document.querySelector('button[b1]')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('b1')
})

// ошибку не должен выдать
try {
  document.querySelector('button[b2]')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('b2')
  })
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<button b1>button</button>
<!-- <button b2>button</button> -->
```

К тому же на подходе [babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)

Comment: Уже работают плагины, использую уже год этот оператор в js и ts. Ваш пример с try имеет недостаток - обработчик в старом браузере вообще не назначится.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev `trycatch` я добавил для просмотра выскочит ли ошибка при явном отсутствии кнопки. Это не пример для реального кодинга.